Should optics and light be the same tag?
I just found out that we have a optics tag and a light. I think we should merge them.

Since optics has the most I suggest the simplest way forward would be to (1) remove light from the eight questions tagged with both, (2) retag light as optics. My understanding is that light will then be deleted by the system. I am not sure whether editing tags bumps a question so it would be best not to do too many per day so as not to flood the front page.
I would be happy to help with this but I do not have the edit privilege yet so I might end up flooding the suggested edits queue.
